Why is BFS is much quicker than DFS when I implement both of them?
I am trying to use DFS and BFS to find all simple paths that have lengths up to a given k, starting at a given vertex in a directed graph. No cycles are allowed.
My code is as follows, and I have verified that both of the algorithms produce correct results.
I define the graph class and put the code of BFS and DFS in this class. There are about 190,000 vertices and 2,500,000 edges in my needed graph. The average out-degree of each vertex is 105:
public class AdjGraph {
    private int V; // sum of vertices
    private int E; // sum of edges
    private List<Vertex> vertexList;
    private Map<Vertex, List<Edge>> vertexAdj;
    
    public AdjGraph() {
        this.V = 0;
        this.E = 0;
        this.vertexList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.vertexAdj = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addVertex(Vertex v) {
        this.vertexList.add(v);
        this.vertexAdj.put(v, new ArrayList<>());
        this.V++;
    }

    public void addEdge(Edge e) {
        Vertex startVertex = e.getStartVertex();
        List<Edge> edgeList = this.vertexAdj.get(startVertex);

        if (!edgeList.contains(e)) {
            edgeList.add(e);
            this.vertexAdj.put(startVertex, edgeList);
        }
    }

    public List<Vertex> getVertexList() {
        return vertexList;
    }

    // Version of DFS
    public Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFS(Vertex start, int k) {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[vertexList.size()];
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> allPaths = new HashMap<>();
        findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil(start, k, visited, path, allPaths);
        return allPaths;
    }

    // Used by the function findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFS(...)
    private void findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil(Vertex u, int k, boolean[] visited, List<Vertex> path, Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> allPaths) {
        // Mark the current node as visited and store in path
        visited[vertexList.indexOf(u)] = true;
        path.add(u);

        // If current path length exceeds k, backtrack
        if (path.size() - 1 > k) {
            visited[vertexList.indexOf(u)] = false;
            path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            return;
        }

        // If current path length is within k, add it to allPaths
        int pathLength = path.size() - 1;
        if (pathLength <= k) {
            allPaths.computeIfAbsent(pathLength, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new ArrayList<>(path));
        }

        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        for (Edge edge : vertexAdj.get(u)) {
            Vertex v = edge.getEndVertex();
            if (!visited[vertexList.indexOf(v)]) {
                findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil(v, k, visited, path, allPaths);
            }
        }

        // Remove current vertex from path and mark it as unvisited
        path.remove(path.size() - 1);
        visited[vertexList.indexOf(u)] = false;
    }

    // Version of BFS
    public Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> findAllPathsUpToLengthByBFS(Vertex start, int k) {
        Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> allPaths = new HashMap<>();
        Queue<List<Vertex>> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        // Initialize the queue with the start vertex
        List<Vertex> startPath = new ArrayList<>();
        startPath.add(start);
        queue.add(startPath);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            List<Vertex> path = queue.poll();
            Vertex last = path.get(path.size() - 1);

            // Add the path to allPaths if its length is within k
            int pathLength = path.size() - 1;
            if (pathLength <= k) {
                allPaths.computeIfAbsent(pathLength, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new ArrayList<>(path));
            }

            // If the path length is already k, no need to explore further
            if (pathLength < k) {
                // Explore the neighbors of the last vertex in the path
                for (Edge edge : vertexAdj.get(last)) {
                    Vertex next = edge.getEndVertex();
                    if (!path.contains(next)) { // Avoid cycles
                        List<Vertex> newPath = new ArrayList<>(path);
                        newPath.add(next);
                        queue.add(newPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return allPaths;
    }
}

Vertex class:
public class Vertex {
    // The origin names are not id1 and id2.
    // I change them for simplicity.
    private String id1;
    private String id2;

    public Vertex() {
    }

    public Vertex(String id1, String id2) {
        this.id1 = id1;
        this.id2 = id2;
    }

    // Getters and Setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;

        return id1.equals(other.id1) && id2.equals(other.id2);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id1, id2);
    }
}

Edge class:
public class Edge {
    private Vertex startVertex;
    private Vertex endVertex;

    public Edge(Vertex startVertex, Vertex endVertex) {
        this.startVertex = startVertex;
        this.endVertex = endVertex;
    }

    // Getters for startVertex and endVertex
    public Vertex getStartVertex() {
        return startVertex;
    }

    public Vertex getEndVertex() {
        return endVertex;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Edge other = (Edge) obj;

        return Objects.equals(startVertex, other.startVertex) &&
                Objects.equals(endVertex, other.endVertex);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(startVertex, endVertex);
    }
}

Here is an example. The data volume of this example is relatively small, so there is not obvious running time difference. When the graph is big, the difference is obvious. In my graph, BFS runs 2ms while DFS runs 15s when k = 1:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AdjGraph graph = new AdjGraph();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Vertex v = new Vertex(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i));
        graph.addVertex(v);
    }

    List<Vertex> vertexList = graph.getVertexList();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vertexList.size(); j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                graph.addEdge(new Edge(vertexList.get(i), vertexList.get(j)));
            }
        }
    }

    Vertex start = vertexList.get(0); // Start node
    int k = 1; // Maximum path length

    Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> allPaths = graph.findAllPathsUpToLengthByBFS(start, k);
//  Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> allPaths = graph.findAllPathsUpToLengthByBFS(start, k);
    Long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Running time: " + (t2 - t1) + "ms");
}

Surprisingly, BFS is much quicker than DFS. Does anybody know why? Maybe it is because there are too many duplicate calculation in DFS? How can I optimize them?
Thanks!

Can you add the code with which you have measured that one is faster than the other? Could you also add the missing class definitions (Vertex, Edge) and methods so we can compile this code and reproduce the timings?

@trincot I will add them right now. They are a little complex.

OK, the more simple you can make it the better. If the time difference can be demonstrated with a graph that has 20 nodes instead of 1000, then that is preferred. If there are methods you have which are not used, don't include them. Just try to be minimalist without losing the runnability and demonstration of the problem.

Thank you for completing the classes. Now we need the (minimal) main driver code that demonstrates that one is faster than the other. Also, there are undefined variables in your code, like tripId, routeId,

@trincot I use a file to generate a big graph. I will try to directly generate an example.  That may take me some time.

I understand But you could create a bigger graph with some symmetry, like A links to B and C, B to C and D, C to D and E, ... etc until you have enough nodes to be significant for the timing. This could be created with some looping.

What is tripId and routeId?

Sorry. It is id1 and id2. I've already corrected them.

@trincot I've added an example and it runs successfully. The running time difference of BFS and DFS can be demonstrated.

OK, just getVertexList is not defined, and main should have a void type.

@trincot My bad. I've now corrected them.

The main reason is that in your DFS implementation, you still look for neighbors when you have already reached the maximum path length. In other words, your base case exit is one level deeper than you could have done, which means a lot of iterations are made without any possibility to add a new path.
This issue can be fixed by changing this part:

        for (Edge edge : vertexAdj.get(u)) {
            Vertex v = edge.getEndVertex();
            if (!visited[vertexList.indexOf(v)]) {
                findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil(v, k, visited, path, allPaths);
            }
        }

to this:
        if (pathLength < k) { // *********
            for (Edge edge : vertexAdj.get(u)) {
                Vertex v = edge.getEndVertex();
                if (!visited[vertexList.indexOf(v)]) {
                    findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil(v, k, visited, path, allPaths);
                }
            }
        }

Note how this is exactly the pattern you used in your BFS implementation.
And with this change you can remove the other base case handling you had:
        // If current path length exceeds k, backtrack
        if (path.size() - 1 > k) {
            visited[vertexList.indexOf(u)] = false;
            path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            return;
        }

There are however more things you can do to improve the DFS implementation, although these will have less dramatic effects:

visited[vertexList.indexOf(v)] is a relatively slow operation when there are many vertices. It would be more efficient to use a hash set instead of an array.
Even better, you could make path an ordered hash set (LinkedHashSet), so that you can drop visited and use path.contains for that purpose.

Here is a version of the DFS implementation that implements those changes. I have named the functions with a "2" at the end so you can include them in your project and compare the performance with your original functions:
    // Improved Version of DFS (DFS2)
    public Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFS2(Vertex start, int k) {
        // Use an insertion-ordered set so you don't need a separate visited array
        Set<Vertex> path = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> allPaths = new HashMap<>();
        findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil2(start, k, path, allPaths);
        return allPaths;
    }

    private void findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil2(Vertex u, int k, Set<Vertex> path, Map<Integer, List<List<Vertex>>> allPaths) {
        path.add(u);
        int pathLength = path.size() - 1;

        allPaths.computeIfAbsent(pathLength, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new ArrayList<>(path));

        if (pathLength < k) { // This is where you should stop recursion
            for (Edge edge : vertexAdj.get(u)) {
                Vertex v = edge.getEndVertex();
                if (!path.contains(v)) {
                    findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil2(v, k, path, allPaths);
                }
            }
        }
        path.remove(u);
    }

Comparing DFS with BFS
Although DFS has an overhead of the call stack, in terms of memory the advantages of DFS over BFS start to weigh in when k gets greater. For instance, I tried your main code, but with a graph of just 25 nodes (instead of 1000), but with k equal to 5. Then we see that BFS turns out to be slower than DFS. This is mainly due to the many partial paths that it stores in memory, while DFS -- by nature -- only uses one partial path.

Thank you so much! Your explanation is incredibly clear and helpful. I genuinely appreciate the time and effort you put into helping me. I will carefully assess how these changes impact the runtime performance:)

You're welcome! ;-)

Hey, I have one more question. The code of the backtracking algorithm tends to include judging if the condition of ending is satisfied at first. If it is satisfied, then return. However, the function "findAllPathsUpToLengthByDFSUtil2" doesn't have this part and still runs successfully. Why?

It is the like the else of the if statement. Instead of that if wrapping statement, we could have had an if statement with the opposite condition, and inside its body do { path.remove(u); return; } , and below that if block you'd have the unwrapped for loop for the recursive case. It all comes down to the same. Sometimes you see an explicit base case, sometimes it is implicit as an omitted else.

Got it! Thanks a lot! The backtracking algorithm is indeed a bit challenging for me, lol.
